# MySQL table partition strange behavior (slow query suddenly)

Tags: mysql, partition

(MySQL version: 5.6.15)

I have a huge table (Table_A) with 10M rows, in entity-attribute-value model.
It has a compound unique key [Field_A + Element + DataTime].

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A 
(
  `Field_A` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `Element` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `DataTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Value` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `A_ELE_TIME` (`Field_A`,`Element`,`DataTime`),
  KEY `DATATIME` (`DataTime`),
  KEY `ELEID` (`ELEID`),
  KEY `ELE_TIME` (`ELEID`,`DataTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Rows are inserted/updated to the table **every minutes**, hence the row size of each [DataTime] (i.e. every minute) is regular, around 3K rows.

I have a "select" query from this table, after the above "inserted/updated".
The query selects one specified elements within most recent 25 hours (around 30K rows). This query usually processes within 3 sec.

```
SELECT 
    Field_A, Element, DataTime, `Value` 
FROM 
    Table_A 
WHERE 
    Element="XX" 
    AND DataTime between [time] and [time].
```

The original housekeeping would be remove any row after 3 days, every 5 minutes.

For better housekeeping, I try to partition the table base on [DataTime], every 6 hours. (00,06,12,18 local time)

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(DataTime)*100+hour(DataTime))
(PARTITION p2014103112 VALUES LESS THAN (73590212) ENGINE = InnoDB,
...
PARTITION p2014110506 VALUES LESS THAN (73590706) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION pFuture VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

My housekeeping script will drop the expired partition then create a new one

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_A REORGANIZE PARTITION pFuture INTO ( 
  PARTITION [new_partition_name] VALUES LESS THAN ([bound_value]), 
  PARTITION pFuture VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
)
```

The new process seems running smoothly.

However, the SELECT query would slow down suddenly (> 100 sec).

The query is still slow even all process stopped. It won't be fixed until "analyzing partitions" (reads and stores the key distributions for partitions).

It usually happens ones a day.

It does not happen to a non-partitioned table.

Therefore, we think it is caused by corrupted indexing in a partitioned MySQL (huge) table.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve it?

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post on the explain result using `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS `.

Comment: Jaugar Chang: EXPLAIN PARTITIONS will query all partitions

Comment: Too many partitions slow down your query. There's no partition solution fit for your query and housekeeping both. But your query would be executed more often than housekeeping. Try to reduce the number of partitions to fit the needs of your query.  By the way, suggest you to migrate this topic to Database Administrators Site, maybe you could get some better answers there.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have asked the in [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82042/mysql-table-partition-strange-behavior-slow-query-suddenly).

Answer (score 0):

If you `PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(DataTime)*100+hour(DataTime))`, when you filter datetime with `between [from] and [to]` operation, mysql will scan all partitions unless `[from]` equals `[to]`.

So it's reasonable that your query slow down suddenly.

My suggestion is partition using `TO_DAYS(DataTime)` without hour, if you query recent 25 hours data, it will scan up to 2 partitions only.

I'm not good at MySql, and I couldn't explain it, wish other smart guys can explain it further. But you could using `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS` to prove it. And here is the [Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d34e/1).